# eclipse scripting: one click, add constructors and getter + setters to a POJO

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to call eclipse Source code generators from a script/ add on?

Many times I make a pojo, like:

```
public class StepState {
    private boolean success;
    private BuildType buildType;
    private String summary;
    private String detail;
}
```

Want to convert it to :

```
public class StepState {
    private boolean success;
    private BuildType buildType;
    private String summary;
    private String detail;

    public StepState() {
        super();
    }

    public StepState(boolean success, BuildType buildType, String summary, String detail) {
        super();
        this.success = success;
        this.buildType = buildType;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public BuildType getBuildType() {
        return buildType;
    }

    public void setBuildType(BuildType buildType) {
        this.buildType = buildType;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }


}
```

Meaning add a constructor from suer class without any arguments. Add a constructor with all elements, add getters and setters for all fields. I guess there are cases like if this class extends another class ... but I want some assumptions to be made, one click and output. Later I can review and edit as needed.

Right now I need to go menu Source, select "Generate Constructors Using Superclass", then "Generate Getters and Setters", and in each step make default choices like select all fields, click okay...
Is there a way to script eclipse and call its features, on a new POJO I make ?

I do not want to see the dialog boxes etc. Just one click and all 3 tasks done.

Comment: I don't think possible at the moment in eclipse, have you tried using some other editor like https://atom.io/packages/java-generator

Comment: @abubakkar yes used that once. but i have a team of developers. much rather scripts for a few things in eclipse that i can commit/ distribute from a repo and use by many programmers.

Answer (score 1):

A Slightly quicker way for you to do this than using the source menu is to simple press - ALT + Shift + S, then go to generate getters and setters.

This way is a lot quicker than doing it through the source menu.

[image]

Comment: A shortcut - yes but really I want a script so I can bunch together tasks, set values, etc. This just brings up the dialog. Saves 1 second of a minute, end to end for the three tasks.